# Running ssh-keygen from inside Azure Function Python runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, azure-functions

Im trying to run a Azure Function app with a SSH Key Generator, but i'm not able to run the ssh-keygen command

I get the following error

> Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -V'

The full stacktrace can be found here
https://pastebin.com/hWev9XFe

The code is very basic - i did a os.listdir to make sure the actual code could see the ssh-keygen and that it was in the path - and it is..

It works on my local machine, running Azure Functions on a local dev env. so really can't see why it should not work here?

The code..

```py
import logging
import subprocess
import uuid
import tempfile
import os

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    idFile = tempfile.gettempdir() + "/key_" + str(uuid.uuid1())
    logging.info(idFile)

    logging.info(os.listdir("/usr/bin/"))

    result = subprocess.run("/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -V", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    logging.info(result.stdout)

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback to your question?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hWev9XFe here it is..

Comment: The code in your question does not match the error, the failing line in your traceback is not found in your question `result = subprocess.run("/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -V", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: now it does - it was the "wanted" code - but i changed it just to dump version of ssh-keygen.. 

The error is just that it cant find the file

Comment: @IainShelvington - guess you are on to something.. The local python does not handle it the same way (On Windows)

Comment: thx @IainShelvington - you had a valid question that led me in the right direction! :-D

Answer (score 0):

Thx to @IainShelvington i was pointed in a direction, the issue was that i did not split up all arguments as shown below i just added the binary and then the arguments as an array value.

Now when all arguments are added into an array it works like a charm

```py
    result = subprocess.run(
        ["/usr/bin/ssh-keygen", "-f", idFile, "-N", '""'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    logging.info(result.stdout)
```